# Match all lines that include StringA but ignore lines that also contain StringB

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I need to match a pattern in a file AND print the following 2 lines. I am using grep -A2 for this.
But I want to ignore some lines from this first grep.

I need the output from the first 'grep -A2' to do some further processing on so piping to grep -v won't help me as far as I understand.

```
$cat file.txt
stringA-hurdygurdy-andmorechars
line1
line2
stringA-hurdygurdy-stringB-andmorechars
line1
line2
stringA-hurdygurdy-andmorechars
line1
line2
```

I need to grep -A2 all the lines that have "stringA-hurdygurdy" but not the ones that contain stringB.

I'm trying
`grep -A2 ^stringA.*[^stringB].* file.txt`

Comment: Dupes are not correct as given `grep` solutions won't work with non-gnu awk as `-A2` is being used. An `awk` would be better solution that `grep` here.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `awk`:

```sh
awk '/stringA/ && !/stringB/ {n = NR+2} n >= NR' file.txt

stringA-hurdygurdy-andmorechars
line1
line2
stringA-hurdygurdy-andmorechars
line1
line2
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. There is a variable named `lines` where we could put how many lines we need to print after matched pattern.

```
awk -v lines="2" '
/^stringA/ && !/stringB/{
  count=0
  found=1
  print
  next
}
found && ++count<=lines
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v lines="2" '           ##Starting awk program from here and setting lines variabnle value to 2.
/^stringA/ && !/stringB/{    ##Checking condition if line contains stringA and DOES NOT contain stringB then do following.
  count=0                    ##Setting count variable to 0 here.
  found=1                    ##Setting found variable to 1 here.
  print                      ##Printing current line here.
  next                       ##next will skip statements from here.
}
found && ++count<=lines      ##Checking condition if found is SET and count(with increasing value of 1) is lesser than lines then print that line.
' Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

With `grep -P` you need a negative lookahead:

```sh
^stringA(?!.*stringB).*$[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*
```

Comment: But what if `stringB` is before `stringA`? I prefere capturing the full line and made a positive lookbehind and a negative lookbehind.

Comment: @rittergig Ask OP. Per their `^stringA` I am assuming they are interested in lines that start with `stringA`

Comment: @rittergig If you're interested then `^(?=.*stringA)(?!.*stringB).*$` would achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner (similar to the awk solution from *anubhava*):

```
perl -lne '$line_num = $. if /stringA/ && !/stringB/; print if $line_num <= $. && $. <= ( $line_num + 2 );' file.txt
```

Output:

```
stringA-hurdygurdy-andmorechars
line1
line2
stringA-hurdygurdy-andmorechars
line1
line2
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing. Its use in this particular case as posted by the OP is optional.

`$.` : current input line number.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the grep syntax but here is the regex which worked for me (.NET regex engine):
`^.*$(?<=stringA.*)(?<!stringB.*)`

You capture a complete line, then you made two look-behinds.

I had to enable the multiline option `/m`.

Test it in .NET:

```cs
Regex newRegex = new Regex(
    @"^.*$(?<=stringA.*)(?<!stringB.*)",
    RegexOptions.Multiline
);
```

Comment: The question is about `grep`, not C#.

Comment: This regex should also be compatible for the engine used in grep.

Comment: No, `grep` can only support PCRE and PCRE does not support infinite width lookbehind patterns.